# Django - Update or Insert based on query

Tags: python, django

Learning how to use Django. I'm trying this code:

```
if form.is_valid() and form.has_changed():
    try:
        p = profile.objects.get(user_id= user.id)
        #Append data to profile record
                    profile_record.save()
    except p.DoesNotExist as e:
        #Create new profile record
        profile_record.save()
```

When `user_id` (FK field) isn't found I get an error:

> local variable 'p' referenced before assignment

I've assumed that `p = ...` is the assignment?

Thank you for any pointers as to what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: What is `p` and what is `profile_record`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to filter the query.. **.get** should always be used in case you know there is going to only one object while querying.

```
if form.is_valid() and form.has_changed():
        p = profile.objects.filter(user_id = user.id)
        if p:
            p = p[0]
            #Append data to profile record
            profile_record.save()
        else:
            #Create new profile record
            profile_record.save()
```

.get(field=something) will always throw error if there is no result or more than 1 result, whereas .filter() does not throw error in these cases.

Comment: Thanks - also found this useful

Answer (score 3):

Your error is occurring because p is first set during the try section.  On except, you reference p, but p has not been assigned to anything at that point, because if the except is reached, then the try section is "undone" and that is where p is assigned.

Try changing `except p.DoesNotExist as e:` to `except Person.DoesNotExist:`

Comment: Thanks Zabari - your answer allowed me to understand my error.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use `get_or_create` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get_or_create

```
p, created = profile.objects.get_or_create(user_id=user.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not using

```
if form.is_valid() and form.has_changed():
    form.save()
```